# the difference the regexp result

Tags: regex

Why ghi's result is different with abc or def?

abc's result is abc: a-b-c-d-e-f

def's result is def: a-b-c-d-e-f

ghi's result is ghi: a-{1}-c-{3}-e-{5}

What is the reason?

```
function abc(){
    var lang = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}";
    var args = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    var exp = /\{(\d+)\}/;
    var matches = exp.exec(lang);
    while (matches) {
        var index = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        lang      = lang.replace(matches[0], args[index]);
        matches   = exp.exec(lang);
    }
    console.log('abc: ' + lang);
}
abc();
function def(){
    var lang = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}";
    var args = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    var exp = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
    var matches = exp.exec(lang);
    while (matches) {
        var exp = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
        var index = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        lang      = lang.replace(matches[0], args[index]);
        matches   = exp.exec(lang);
    }
    console.log('def: ' + lang);
}
def();
function ghi(){
    var lang = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}";
    var args = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    var exp = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
    var matches = exp.exec(lang);
    while (matches) {
        var index = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        lang      = lang.replace(matches[0], args[index]);
        matches   = exp.exec(lang);
    }
    console.log('ghi: ' + lang);
}
ghi();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `ghi()` needs to reset `RegExp` object's `lastIndex` inside the loop:

```
function ghi(){
    var lang = "{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}";
    var args = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    var exp = /\{(\d+)\}/g;
    while (matches = exp.exec(lang)) {
        var index = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
        lang      = lang.replace(matches[0], args[index]);
        exp.lastIndex = 0;
    }
    console.log('ghi: ' + lang);
}
```

Because of `exp.lastIndex = 0;` call now output will be same.

> JavaScript's `RegExp` object is stateful. When global flag is used, and you call a method the same `RegExp` object, it will start on the next index from the end of the last match.

Comment: Your answers have been very useful to me. Thank you!